# Wordpress loop assistance needed

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am working on using the wordpress loop to call posts from my wordpress blog into my website.  i have my loop set up to grab the 10 most recent posts under the portfolio category and display them on my portfolio page.  the problem is that i have 20 items i want to display, but i don't want to have to deal with the load times of 20 images.  ive thought about making multiple portfolio pages in dreamweaver, and have each one grab a different set of ten posts, but that's defeating the purpose of using wordpress to make it faster for me to update the page.

is there any way i can have it set up so that when i hit 'next' the page refreshes with the next set of ten posts, and when i hit 'back' the page refreshes with the first ten posts?

i have seen webpages that are like www.example.com/portfolio.php?paged=2

Here is my header that calls the loop

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp/wp-load.php');
query_posts('category_name=portfolio&posts_per_page=10');
```

and here is where the loop gets placed on the page

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

any help greatly appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: You would be better off asking this at the [Wordpress-specific Stack Exchange site.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: More specifically, you may be interested in [the answers to the several questions related to custom loop pagination](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 $paged = get_query_var('paged');

query_posts(array(
'category_name'=>'portfolio',
posts_per_page'=>10
'paged' => $paged // set the current page
));
```

Comment: that caused a problem.  it took me to a wordpress page with the content.  i need the content to be changed to the earlier posts

Comment: you set the paged variable in the url

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.  is there any way you could show me how i would do that?

Comment: is as you said www.example.com/portfolio?paged=2

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean

Comment: you can pass the paged variable in the query_post function if paged is 1, query_posts return the first ten (1 - 10) posts if paged is 2 return(11 - 20) 3 return(21 - 30) try add the paged variable in hard code maybe this help you to understand how this work `category_name=portfolio&posts_per_page=10&paged=2'